# Dynamically pre populate comments into chat box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dashboard in which a chat box is included. I have searched for resources online and came up with a simple UI using bootstrap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .chat
        {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .chat li
        {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #B3A9A9;
        }

        .chat li.left .chat-body
        {
            margin-left: 60px;
        }

        .chat li.right .chat-body
        {
            margin-right: 60px;
        }


        .chat li .chat-body p
        {
            margin: 0;
            color: #777777;
        }

        .panel .slidedown .glyphicon, .chat .glyphicon
        {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .panel-body
        {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 250px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track
        {
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar
        {
            width: 12px;
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
        {
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            background-color: #555;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading" id="accordion">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="chat">
                        <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/50/55C1E7/fff&text=U" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                        </span>
                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <strong class="primary-font">Jack</strong> 
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Comment 1.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                        </span>
                            <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                <div class="header">
                                    <strong class="primary-font">Harry</strong> 
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Harry - Comment
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                            </span>
                                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <strong class="primary-font">Harry</strong> 
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        Harry - Comment2
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                                Send</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here each **li** element has html code in the following format.

```html
<li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                        </span>
  <div class="chat-body clearfix">
    <div class="header">
      <strong class="primary-font">Harry</strong>
    </div>
    <p>
      Some Comment.
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

I am trying to prepopulate past comments from database. I get a map of names and their comments sorted in the order of time. For example the map could be something like
{Jack: Comment1, Harry: Comment2....}

I want to dynamically fill the **p** tag with comment, name within **strong** tag from the map that I obtain from database. could someone help me on this?

Comment: You will want to show your generated jSON also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template :

```html
<template id="comment-template">
  <li class="left clearfix">
    <span class="chat-img pull-left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
    </span>
    <div class="chat-body clearfix">
      <div class="header">
        <strong class="primary-font"></strong>
      </div>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>

<div id="comments-cnt"></div>
```

I assume data is something like :

```js
const comments = [
  { jack: 'comment1' },
  { harry: 'comment2' },
  { david: 'comment3' }
]
```

Then iterate over this array, clone the template, populate it with name, comment from each object literal and insert it into the container :

```js
let commentCnt = document.getElementById('comments-cnt')
const template = document.getElementById('comment-template')

comments.forEach(function(c) {
  //extract data
  const name = Object.keys(c)[0]
  const comment = c[name]

  //create clone of the template and populate       
  let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true)
  clone.querySelector('strong').innerText = name
  clone.querySelector('p').innerText = comment

  //insert
  commentCnt.appendChild(clone)
})
```

The structure of your `<li>` element / template makes it very easy.

Comment: what if the elements that I want to populate belong to same class type? would this work? clone.querySelector('p').innerText = name
  clone.querySelector('p').innerText = comment

Comment: I think so. As long you are waling trough a domain i.e `getElementById('top').getElementById('left')` and so on, then `..getElementsByClassName` should only return the innner